# Error-Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I am developing an application to transfer data between two databases in C#. I have a method to insert BLOB type data in MySQL. While executing it I am getting error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

Code#

```
public static void FiletoSql(MemoryStream fileToPut, MySqlConnection con)
    {
      try
      {
       const string preparedCommand =
       @"update user_account_statement set STATEMENT_FILE=@ssfile, create_date_time=@udatetime where statement_Id=1070";
       using (var sqlWrite = new MySqlCommand(preparedCommand, con))
       {
         sqlWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssfile", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = fileToPut.ToArray();
         sqlWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udatetime", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value =
         DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
         sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
      }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
   }
```

I am not getting exactly what is problem in converting.

**Edit**: I've tried this:

```
var fileData=new MySqlParameter("@ssfile",MySqlDbType.Blob,data.Length) {
    Value = data
};
sqlWrite.Parameters.Add(fileData);
sqlWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udatetime", MySqlDbType.DateTime)
                   .Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
var cmd = sqlWrite;
sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And now I am getting error Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: sounds like you'll have to implement the interface?

Comment: @Noctis no it just a method to insert data into a MySQL table.

Comment: seems you look for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13208599/1328536

Comment: It seems like what you want is to create a query with a parameter from similar questions. Oh, **Fuchs** said the same it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow!! Got the answer.

**Tested solution:**

```
public static void FiletoSql(MemoryStream fileToPut, MySqlConnection con)
    {
        byte[] data = fileToPut.ToArray();
        try
        {
            const string preparedCommand =
                @"update user_account_statement set STATEMENT_FILE=@ssfile, create_date_time=@udatetime where statement_Id=1070";

            using (var sqlWrite = new MySqlCommand(preparedCommand, con))
            {
                sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@ssfile", MySqlDbType.Blob);
                sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("udatetime", MySqlDbType.DateTime);

                sqlWrite.Parameters["@ssfile"].Value = data;
                sqlWrite.Parameters["udatetime"].Value=DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Noctis your guidance appreciated. :)

Comment: @fuchs777 your guidance appreciated.