# Parameter Not Valid Error c# while retriving saved image from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have created image column in table as `mediumblob`

to save image i used following code

```
byte[] ImageData;
fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
ImageData = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)];
fs.Read(ImageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();

string qry = "Update admin_info set `img`='"+ ImageData + "' where id='AD001";

using (con = new MySqlConnection(DBConStr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, con))
    {
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
    MessageBox.Show(" Profile Picture Updated Successfully!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

and it was sucessfull but m getting parameter invalid while retrieving it to picture box using below code

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Port = 3307; database = attendance; uid = root; pwd = MJN45720!"))
{
     conn.Open();
     string myQuery = "SELECT img FROM admin_info where id='AD001'";

     using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myQuery, conn))
     {
         using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                   byte[] x = (byte[])reader["img"];
                   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(x);
                   pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms); //Parameter invalid in this line
               }
         }
     }
```

searched many forums and tired all they suggesting in every posts but im unable to solve..

Comment: I think you will find the data saved has been corrupted by your method of storing it - see here for the correct way to save images. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208349/how-to-insert-blob-datatype

Comment: yes u are ryt.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't saving image into DB correctly.
Line ``` string qry = "Update admin_info set ``img``='"+ ImageData + "' where id='AD001"; ``` will result in
 ``` qry = "Update admin_info set ``img``='System.Byte[]' where id='AD001 ``` because you are converting byte array to string which will result in type name only.
You will have to convert byte array to HEX string which should be accepted by SQL engine.

Comment: thanks for pointing out.. i solved it using sql parameters qry

Answer (score 0):

```
        byte[] ImageData;
        fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        br.Close();
        fs.Close();

       using (con = new MySqlConnection(DBConStr))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pimage", MySqlDbType.Blob);
                cmd.Parameters["@pimage"].Value = ImageData;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

This solved my probelm and im able to retrive too.. Thanks [Honz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089492/honzaa) for pointing out the actual problem for converting it to sting :)