# Storing PDF files in SQL server database

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to save a PDF file into my database table is there any proper way to do this. I am working with C++/CLI.

I have tried this code below but I am getting System.byte[] instead of actual value

```
    FileStream^ fs = gcnew FileStream("E:\\test.pdf",FileMode::Open,FileAccess::Read);
    BinaryReader^ br=gcnew BinaryReader(fs);
cli::array<System::Byte>^ Mybuffer=gcnew cli::array<System::Byte>(fs->Length);
Mybuffer =br->ReadBytes(Convert::ToInt32(fs->Length));

SqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew SqlCommand
    ("Insert Into Employees(empName,branchGuid,cvFile) values ('" + textBox1->Text + "',(select branchGuid from Branches where branchName='" + branchesComboBox->SelectedValue->ToString() + "')," + Mybuffer +");", conn);
      SqlDataAdapter^ sda = gcnew SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet^ ds = gcnew DataSet();
      sda->Fill(ds, "insert");
```

Comment: That's not C++ but a dialect called C++/CLI.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability. Please use the [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of SqlCommand or related techniques to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is where you're concatenating the buffer into the SQL command.

```
+ Mybuffer +");"
```

`Mybuffer` is of type `array<Byte>^`. When you do the string concatenation on something other than a string, it calls `ToString()`. The .Net array class doesn't output the array contents when ToString is called, it just does the default behavior, which is to output the class name (In C# format, so `[]` instead of `array<>`).

You haven't said how the `cvFile` field of the `Employees` table is defined. You'll need to either iterate over the byte array and create the SQL statement with the value of all the bytes, or you may need to use some other API to insert the data. If it's a BLOB type, see this answer, there's a lot of good concepts there: [How to insert BLOB datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208599/480937)